# FlexBoxLayout - How to stretch buttons only when wrapped?

Tags: android, flexbox, android-flexboxlayout

I am trying to implement a view of two buttons that will behave one way when there's room for the buttons to be rendered next to each other, and in another way when there isn't.

### Here are the requirements:

When buttons are short enough:

- Buttons should appear with space between them.
- Button size should wrap the text.
- Negative button should be on the left, positive on the right.

When one of the button's text is too long:

- Buttons should be one on top of the other.
- Button size fill the entire width.
- Positive button should be on top of the negative button.

### Here's an illustration of the expected layout:

[image]

### Here's my code so far:

```xml
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:flexDirection="row"
    app:flexWrap="wrap_reverse"
    app:alignItems="center">

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:id="@+id/negative_btn"
      style="@style/OutlinedButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:id="@+id/positive_btn"
      style="@style/TonalButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

[image]

So my question is, how can I make the bottom button look like the expected Case B?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a below line in each button and it will grow to match parent

> app:layout_flexGrow="1.0"

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:flexDirection="row"
            app:justifyContent="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:flexWrap="wrap_reverse"
            app:alignItems="center">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/negative_btn"
                android:textFontWeight="1"
                android:text="first here is my version of thenbbhefbhfbhjefbhjfbhf "
                app:layout_flexGrow="1.0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/positive_btn"
                android:text="second"
                android:textFontWeight="1"
                app:layout_flexGrow="1.0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: This will cause the two buttons in Case A to fill all space between them, which is not good...